# Event not getting cleared

Tags: c#, .net

I am adding a changed event ot an observable collection.

```
var someList = new Observablecollection<ITCardBase>();
someList.CollectionChanged+=Changed;

void Changed(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Action==System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        if(e.NewItems[0] is ITCardBase)
        {
            ITCardBase eq = (ITCardBase)e.NewItems[0];
            eq.Unsubscribe(TCardClickedInList);
            eq.Subscribe(TCardClickedInList);
        }
    }

}
//this just allows a user control to be clicked and bind to the event
public virtual void Subscribe(Func<ITCardBase, int> myMethodName)
{       
    TCardClick += myMethodName.Invoke;          
}
public virtual void Unsubscribe(Func<ITCardBase, int> myMethodName)
{             
    TCardClick -= myMethodName.Invoke;
}
public int TCardClickedInList(ITCardBase card)
{
    //click event when the user clicks the "card" user control"
    return 0;
}
```

The issue I am having is that when I clear my list, and then re-add the items from my database, the click event gets duplicated, so it gets called twice, then tree times, etc. So clearing SomeList does not seem to remove the events on the objects inside them, even though they should be gone.

How can I properly "clear" the items in the list, so when they get added from the database again(they are the same items), it doesn't duplicate this event. I tried doing an Unsubscribe(), which doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

```
 public void ReloadTCards()
    {
        if (SubTCardList != null)
        {

         foreach(ITCardBase card in SubTCardList)
         {
             card.Unsubscribe(TCardClickedInList);
         }//I TRIED unsubscribg each element before I clear the list
          //but then when I readd the items to the list, the same issue happens

            SubTCardList.Clear();
            LoadSubTCardsWithIncidentID(TCardLoadedIncidentId);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you do `Subscribe` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: why can't you subscribe once. instead of every change

Comment: Also note that you only handle `Add`. When you do `Reset` or `Clear` on the list that code won't get called. It should unsubscribe if the same element is passed to the list again though. Your description is a bit vague regarding "clearing [..] does not seem to remove [..]"

Comment: This system seems really contrived. Although it won't answer your question, it might help to understand what the point of all this is.

Comment: Subscribe is not called anywhere else. I need each user contrl "card" to subscribe to the click event, as each one is a derived class and a different type, and does a different action on the click. I USED to hangle Clear, but when I clear, I do not have access to any of the equipment, so I can't unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public virtual void Subscribe(Func<ITCardBase, int> myMethodName)
    {

        TCardClick = null;//THIS FIXED EVERYTHING
        TCardClick += myMethodName.Invoke;          
    }
```

I merely null the event, as on the second time subscribe is called(when the list is being added to again) this was not null as it was the first time.